# Selecting top 10% of the customers using SQL query

Tags: sql

I have a table known as Customers.
I want to fetch 10% of the customers based on the order they appear in the table.
I am not sure about how to do this in SLQ?

I know I can use "top" and specify the number. But since the customer count changes everyday I want to pick this up based on the %.

Example what I tried,

```
select top 100 email-address, cid 
from Customers
```

Comment: `top` is an MS-SQL syntax, but your question is tagged with [tag:mysql]. Which one are you using?

Comment: If using `SELECT TOP 100` works for you, then it is likely that `SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT....` would also work (or whatever percent you want). It would also suggest that your tags are not correct

Comment: And, of course, `SELECT TOP whatever` without an `ORDER BY` clause gives you an unpredictable assortment of the rows in the table.  Rows in tables *have no inherent order*.

Comment: `email-address` is read as `email minus address`. Column names with odd characters need to be delimited, like `"email-address"`, or perhaps SQL Server special `[email-address]`